# Some video required a lot of time to play with AVPlay

Tags: avplayer, mp4, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator

I tested AVplay, NaCL, videoJS on tizen samsung emulator and samsung device but i found some videos which requires a lot of time to start to play.

This is a video [sample](https://playtime.tubemogul.com/ad_promoted_videos/c6058f7d-dbd5-4d08-8dcf-16f82b0a97d2.mp4) with the problem. Using Chrome browser, any library works but the issue is when I try to samsung emulator/device.

Samsung forum does not help in fact, that is why I preferred to ask here.

Comment: Try running “faststart” on the file (ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -movflags +faststart out.mp4)

Comment: Are you using `webapis.avplay.prepareAsync()` with AVPlay?

Comment: @daleyjem yes I an